# Uncaught ReferenceError: var is undefined when testing for truthy

Tags: javascript

So,
I have always used the type of construction for testing the presence of variables:

```
if(foo){
   doThings();
}
```

Now, I'm getting an

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is undefined
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qVVgy/1/)

it's a fact that the var was never even declared.
My question is, is this normal behaviour? I've used this many times and i think this is not the first time the variable is not declared; i'm almost sure that i never had a problem with this, it just returned false and didn't get in the condition.

Any help and clarification is welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a variable has not been *declared* then an attempt to reference it will result in a reference error.

If a variable has been declared but not assigned a value then it will implicitly have the value `undefined` and your code will work as expected.

In your case, this is what happens:

- [Evaluate the `if` statement](http://es5.github.io/#x12.5) [if ( *Expression* ) *Statement*]

  - This involves evaluating *Expression*, which returns a reference, as per [10.3.1](http://es5.github.io/#x10.3.1)
  - Call [GetValue](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7.1) on the returned reference

    - If the reference is not resolvable (it's value is `undefined`), **throw a reference error**
  - Coerce the value of the reference to a boolean value

The algorithm for determining the value of a reference traverses the chain of nested lexical environments until it reaches the outermost context. When it reaches that point and still does not find a binding for the provided identifier it returns a reference whose base value is `undefined`.

When the base value of a reference is `undefined` that reference is said to be "[unresolvable](http://es5.github.io/#IsUnresolvableReference)", and when a reference is unresolvable any attempt to reference it will result (unsurprisingly) in a reference error.

Comment: i edited the question. I wasn't using "var" it was just an alias here

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez - I know, my answer has nothing to do with the identifier you're using.

Comment: sorry, this comment wasn't for you :) your answer is the right one. thank you

Comment: @JamesAllardice Then why does `if (undefined) {
    console.log("Welcome");
}` this does not throw any error?

Comment: @thefourtheye - Because `undefined` does not result in a undefined *reference*. It results in the `undefined` value. That's somewhat similar to `if (0) { /*...*/ }`

Comment: You mean, `undefined` is a global property and during the traversal it finds it?

Comment: Yes, but in this case it's easier to think of `undefined` as a primitive value, like `null` where there is no traversal necessary and the expression is evaluated as per [section 7.8](http://es5.github.io/#x7.8).

Answer (score 2):

check the updated fiddle. If you haven't declare a variable then in condition u will have to check its type.

```
var a = 1;
var b;


try{
    if(typeof(c)!='undefined') {
        alert("OK");   
    }
} catch(ex){
    alert(ex);
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qVVgy/2/)

Comment: thank you, i knew this; i just didn't know that what i asked was default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

`var` is a *reserved keyword* in Javascript.

The following is the corresponding error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var
```

Comment: i edited the question. I wasn't using "var" it was just an alias here